# How to get a variable out of a function without using ()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to develop a GUI for a simple program i did, for this one i need to ask for a folder which is goint to be the one analized, and i want to print the direction of the selected folder, but when i call the variable "direccion" it doesnt appear.

And basically all i want is to print the direction into the label called Entry, sorry for that name but i tried to make it an Entry and in this one print the direction but i think it's harder. Thank you.

This is what i have so far:

```
#Importados
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

#Root
root = Tk()
root.title('INTERFAZ COMPOSICION DE BANDAS')
root.iconbitmap('ICON.ico')
root.config(bg='gray')
root.resizable(1,1)

#Frame
frame=Frame(root,width=480,height=320)
frame.config(cursor="arrow")
frame.pack(side='top')


#Label
Labeltitulo = Label(frame,text='Composicion de bandas')
Labeltitulo.grid(row=0,column=1)

#Buscador Directorio
imagen=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\57314\Documents\AUTOMATING\COMP_RGB\folder.png')
pic=imagen.subsample('3','3')
def buscador():
    global direccion
    direccion = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,title='Escoge carpeta a analizar')
    print (direccion)
    return direccion

BotonFolder = Button(frame,text='Click me',image=pic,command=buscador).grid(row=1,column=0)


Labeldirectorio=Label(frame,text='Ingresa directorio')
Labeldirectorio.grid(row=3,column=0)


#Pasting directorio
dasasas = buscador
entry = Label(frame,text=dasasas)
entry.grid(row=1,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: On the line: dasasas = buscador you are just storing the function in the variable. If you want to run the function you need to put () behind the function. So if you add the () behind buscador, you should get the expected result.

Comment: You should set the text of label `entry` inside `buscador()`: `entry['text'] = direccion`.

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback error. I cannot reproduce your error as is. Removing the Arcpy and image links to test your code the filedialog works as expected so I need to know where you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reduced version of your code taking out all the irrelevant parts to your question.

You do not need to add something to global if you are updating a label in the global name space.

Simply configure that labels text.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def buscador():
    direccion = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, title='Escoge carpeta a analizar')
    path_lbl.config(text=direccion)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=480, height=320)
frame.pack(side='top')
tk.Label(frame, text='Composicion de bandas').grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(frame, text='Click me', command=buscador).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(frame, text='Ingresa directorio').grid(row=3, column=0)
path_lbl = tk.Label(frame, text='Choose a folder to analize')
path_lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much men this is what i needed and i am terrible at even asking the proper question, thanks.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca no problem. If this answered your question please select the check mark next to the answer to show your issue has been resolved.